# Theme installation in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, theme, installation

*I have installed my theme on localhost and its working fine*.

*I have my default magento 2.3  setup on server.*

*I need to install the same theme on server.*

*Can anyone say which folder i need to copy?*

**Is it just 'app' and 'pub'???**

Comment: Did you fix issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your theme directory

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme` to server

and then run these command to generate static files in pub

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Edit:**
The best practice is to use git, and setup git on your local and server. Commit all the changes from local and get pull on server.

Magento 2 gives you `.gitignore` file by default, it will prevent static files to be committed, so you don't need to worry about which needs to be commit. Just commit your code and get pull on production server.

Git has also revert criteria, but this would be off topic, it would be better that you study on git and implement on your project.